# VS code не открывает браузер после запуска сервера

Tags: json, сервер, visual-studio-code, запуск

#### Описание

Есть у меня самая простая задача в `tasks.json` для запуска сервера:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start server",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "http-server -p 3000",
        }
    ],
}
```

И есть конфигурация в `launch.json` которая должна запустить эту задачу и потом открыть браузер по этому адресу:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "preLaunchTask": "start server",
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Все бы хорошо, но после запуска конфигурации, которая в свою очередь запускает сервер, браузер не открывается, а открывается после остановки сервера.
Думаю проблема в том, что конфигурация `launch.json` ждет окончания задачи в `tasks.json` и потом уже продолжает выполнение.

#### Вопрос

Как исправить этот момент, чтобы браузер открылся сразу после запуска сервера?